# mfirstuc's \capitalisewords behave inconsistently

Tags: formatting, titles, mfirstuc

In my document, when I use `\capitalisewords{\@title}`, it makes all the letters in the title uppercase. But when I do `\capitalisewords{The Actual title in words}`, it works fine (makes only the first letters of the words caps.

I want to understand why this happens.

Comment: Noticed just now that this happens anytime I assign the string I want to capitalize as a command and use it inside `\capitalisewords`

Comment: Try `\expandafter\capitalisewords\expandafter{\@title}`.

Comment: That worked. But why?

Comment: Because a macro does not automatically expand its argument before operating upon it. `\@title` is a single token.  Only upon expansion does it become a string of letters and spaces.